# Android _ redirect from a service class to another Activity?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Can I redirect from a `service class` to another `Activity` ?

I need that when my process finish in service redirect me to another activity .

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this ?

```
 Intent in=new Intent().setClass(MyAlarmService.this,Reminder.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(in);
```

**Edit :**

If you are using BroadcastReceiver try this

```
Intent iAlarm = new Intent( mcontext, YourActivity.class );
                     iAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND); 
                     iAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
mcontext.startActivity(iAlarm);
```

Comment: it is a bad practice to start Activities right from the Service, you should use Notifications instead

Answer (score 0):

When your process get finish send the broadcast and when you receive the broadcast  **onReceive** method start your next activity. ELSE use **Intent Service**